# How to add nested data into a Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

My scenario is that I am trying to build a dictionary from a json request and I'm getting a `KeyError` when trying to insert data into nested levels.

I've done `requests.get(url)` which gave me existing data that I tried to add to an empty dictionary, but while assigning to empty dictionary it's giving error as the value is nested.

Example:

I have a dictionary

```
temp = {}
```

I am unable to assign the value to

```
temp["conf"]["data"]["network"] = GET call data
```

its throwing error saying `keyError`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

When you use `[key]` on a dict, you get the value of that key.

I think you want`temp["conf"]` to return a dict but currently `temp["conf"]` is undefined so you get a key error because it does not exist. A good way to use dict in Python is [get](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) because it will return `None` when the key does not exist (instead of KeyError). This allows you to gracefully handle the error.

I think this will fix your problem (the structure of your data and the structure you want is not known so you will need to make some changes but this will give you an idea to get started),

```py
temp = {}
temp["conf"] = {}
temp["conf"]["data"] = {}
temp["conf"]["data"]["network"] = <value>
```

The KeyError comes becaues the key does not exist so the 2nd and 3rd lines simply define an empty dict for that key.

Maybe useful tip: If you want to convert a json into a dict in python, use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: you mention a good way to use dict in Python is get but then dont explain at all how to use it and dont use it yourself; suggest you either make use of it or don't mention it, or mention why get is better.  In this case it's unclear how get would dramatically improve things. good answer!

Answer (score 0):

The other option that is an alternative to what is mentioned by @rkochar is to use a `DefaultDictionary` instead of a Dictionary, where in you specify that the first two layers are also `DefaultDictionary`'s so that you dont have to create the nested layers explicitly.  This has drawbacks in that it forces a level of homogenity into the final dictionary that you may not want.  There are many other questions which explain how to use nested DefaultDictionaries so I'm not going to repost them here.

The crux of your problem is that in an empty dictionary that you start with you can't just write to a nesting level several deep. in your attempted assignment `temp["conf"]["data"]["network"] = <value>` the first key lookup for "conf" will fail because the dictionary is empty. You have to code in that key should have a value of a dictionary. Similarly for the "data" key to the dictionary value of key "conf".

An aside is that you would be better served by using `json.dumps` from the `request` data which will automatically create a dictionary for you that you can edit, and then use.

Answer (score 0):

One trick that builds an arbitrarily deep [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) structure:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

temp = tree()
temp["conf"]["data"]["network"] = "foo"
```

This saves the boilerplatish and illegible:

```
temp.setdefault("conf", {}).setdefault("data", {})["network"] = "foo"
```